# How to get the count of elements in string through java

Tags: java

Example: Suppose, String contains (AA, BB, CC) then out put should be 3. Can some one tell how to get this result.

I tried like this

```
String userValues= "AA,BB,CC"
int selecteditems=userValues.length();
```

But I didnt get the result as 3.

Comment: you should split and then look at length

Comment: Are you sure String is what you need? What is the real problem? (If it is, accept one of the answers mentioning `split()`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
userValues.split(",").length
```

this should do the trick

Comment: arrays have a member `length` not a method `length()`

Comment: yep, was trying to be fast :)

Comment: @Ameoo You got the attention in that one line... I'll take my revenge.. someday.. :D

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] splitted = userValues.split(",");
int selectedItems = splitted.length;
```

**Tip**: Always refer to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and see what they have to say, this will save for you a lot of efforts and time.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I don't like the solutions that create a temporary string array then evaluates the array length, as doing all that is expensive in terms of performance.

Use this instead if performance matters

```
int num = 0;
for (int i = 0; 
     i < userValues.length(); 
     num += (userValues.charAt(i++) == ',' ? 1 : 0));
/* num holds the occurrences */
```

But I agree that the solution [acknowledge Ameoo]

```
userValues.split(",").length
```

is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String[] separatedValues = userValues.split(",");
int selecteditems = separatedValues.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String userValues= "AA,BB,CC"
String x[]=userValues.split(",");
System.out.println(x.length);
```

**output**
3

Comment: You're a C programmer, aren't you? ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun why do you think that?

Comment: Because `String x[]` and not `String[] x` :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun could not understand what you meant to say

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] splitedArray = userValues.split(",");
int count = splitedArray.length; //remenber length not length()
```

Here is java doc [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

Splits this string around matches of the given [regular expression.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)

Answer (score 0):

If values are separated by comma, 
then you could use

```
string.split(",");
```

and then get length

Comment: This won't compile, please fix it.

Comment: String[] parts = UserValues.split(",");
   int length = parts.length;

Answer (score 0):

You should first split the string by comma character.

`String[] split= userValues.split(",");`

Then just get the length of `split` array using

`int len = split.length`

Answer (score 0):

The other responses suggest splitting the string. This is fine for short strings, but will use more memory than necessary which could have a performance impact if you're processing long strings. An alternative is to use a regex to match the components of the string you want to count:

```java
    String s = "AA,BB,CC";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "([A-Z]+,?)" );
    int count = 0, i = 0;
    Matcher m = p.matcher( s );
    while (m.find( i )) {
        count++;
        i = m.end();
    }
    System.out.println( count );
```

Comment: any reasons why you say **This is fine for short strings, but will use more memory than necessary which could have a performance impact if you're processing long strings.**

Comment: The `split()` operation will create as many string objects as there are substrings, and each one requires the allocation of memory. It's not as bad in Java as some languages, since Java strings are immutable and so the substring objects will share the character data with the string they are split from.